# Routing Url that has no action name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, routes

How to route this url
`http://localhost:1986/en/Hotel/#forward`

to

```
controller = "Hotel",
action = "Results"
```

Since I need to refresh this page when the user sign in from this page, I need to redirect to the above said controller/action.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have found some solution my self

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "HotelResultAfterFlightSelection1", // Route name
   "Hotel/Results/{tripid}", // URL with parameters
   new
   {
       controller = "Hotel",
       action = "Results",
       tripid = UrlParameter.Optional
   }
);
routes.MapRoute(
   "HotelResultAfterFlightSelection2", // Route name
   "Hotel", // URL with parameters
   new
   {
       controller = "Hotel",
       action = "Results"
   }
);
```